# Inserting Record from one table into another Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

All, Trying to make this code work.

This is a part of stored procedure called within another stored procedure; and inserts records from one table into another, but I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

```
** Main Procedure **
EXEC [dbo].[usr_INSERTRECORD] ABC, @TableName, @TransDate, @Symbol

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_INSERTRECORD]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SourceTable SYSNAME,
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @TransDate Date,
    @Symbol nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @DATEVARCHAR nvarchar(4000);
    SET @DATEVARCHAR = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @TransDate, 103);
    DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + + QUOTENAME(@SourceTable) 
        + ' WHERE (TRANSDATE = ' + '''' + @DATEVARCHAR + '''' +') ' + 'AND (SYMBOL = ' + '''' + @SYMBOL + '''' +')';

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters instead of inserting the values in the string.  You are already using `sp_executesql`, so this is just using it better:

```
DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceTable) + '
      WHERE TRANSDATE = @TransDate AND SYMBOL = @SYMBOL' ;

EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql]  @sqlCommand,
                               N'@TransDate date, @Symbol varchar(50)',
                               @TransDate = @TransDate, @Symbol = @Symbol;
```

Also, when using `VARCHAR()` in SQL, always include a length.  The default length depends on the context, and leaving it out is an easy way to make a mistake.

Presumably, the cause of your error is in executing the generated SQL code.  Format 103 is "dd/mm/yyyy", which may or may not convert back to a date correctly.  If you really want to represent a date as a string, I recommend always using the ISO standard formats of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.

Comment: `WHERE TRANSDATE = @TransDate AND SYMBOL = @SYMBOL` Remove `(` or add closing one

Answer (score 0):

That worked. Thank you Gordon. Here is the final code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_INSERTRECORD]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SourceTable SYSNAME,
    @TableName SYSNAME,
    @TransDate Date,
    @Symbol nvarchar(50)
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @DATEVARCHAR nvarchar(4000);
    SET @DATEVARCHAR = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @TransDate, 103);
    DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + + QUOTENAME(@SourceTable) 
        + ' WHERE (TRANSDATE = @TransDate AND SYMBOL = @SYMBOL)';

EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql]  @sqlCommand,
                               N'@TransDate date, @Symbol nvarchar(50)',
                               @TransDate = @TransDate, @Symbol = @Symbol;
END
```